# Scaling from Firebase to Firebase on private server

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, firebase

I'm developing an iOS app that will contain sensitive health-data. AWS seems to have [several health-focused clients](https://aws.amazon.com/health/) that work with them (and probably have a VPS with them). The learning curve seems to be pretty steep for this.

I've familiarised myself with Firebase, which I really like. My plan is to use Firebase's Google cloud option for testing the app while I'm developing it, when the preliminary mock data I gather isn't sensitive. Then, I was going to set-up a VPS or private server with a company like Rackspace (UK-based), and then use this documentation to set-up Firebase on that [server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup).

Does that seem stupid? I'm new to this, so any suggestions would be appreciated -- I'm looking for recommendations on how to set this up, bearing in mind that I'd like to quickly test things now and then scale up (and eventually keep the data as secure as possible).

Comment: Firebase is not HIPAA compliant so you really don't want to store any kind of patient data in it. Secondly, Firebase doesn't have a private server model and is not supported by Rackspace.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks (I had incorrectly assumed that Firebase was on Google Cloud which seems to be HIPAA complaint). So you would recommend using Amazon (Mobile SDK) and their DynamoDB then?

Comment: I'll say this before someone else does... Stackoverflow is specifically for coding questions, so non-programming, recommendations or opinion based questions should be avoided [What to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That being said, what service you go with is totally dependent on your use case. Because you need HIPAA compliance, that significantly narrows the field. From there do you need NoSQL? SQL? Storage? To you need real-time updates? Push notifications? There's lots to consider and a number of options. [Catalyze](https://catalyze.io) has an iOS API that looks interesting.